# Como modificar apenas a linha da legenda que identifica o grupo?

Tags: r, ggplot2

Como posso alterar apenas a espessura das linhas coloridas da legenda que identificam os grupos?

Não envio o `dput()` do gráfico pq são mais de 40 mil linhas. Envio um recorte da figura para identificar meu problema e envio o código de geração do gráfico.
Tentei algumas opções mexendo no `Theme()` mas não consegui mudar.

```
require(ggplot2)

pl <- ggplot(TEPT_CONT_TA_TOC, aes(x = time, y = value, colour = grupo,
                 group = interaction(grupo, variable))) +
  geom_line(alpha = 0.5) + geom_smooth(aes(group = grupo), colour = "black") +
  scale_x_continuous(name = "Tempo em segundos",
                     limits = c(0,300),
                     breaks = seq(0,300,by = 60)) +
  scale_y_continuous(name = expression(paste("(",mu,"S)"))) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(face = "bold",size = 12),
        legend.title = element_text(size = 12),
        legend.key = element_rect(fill = "white"),
        legend.background = element_rect(fill = "white")) +
  labs(title = "Resposta Galvânica da Pele",
       subtitle = "Behavioral Endocrinology Lab",
       colour = "Grupo")
```

[image: Pedaço da imagem do gráfico.]

> Como deixo essas linhas mais espessas para facilitar a identificação
>   do grupo?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Uma solução pode ser encontrada no [Stack Overflow em Inglês](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19456816/ggplot2-change-legend-symbol).
Vou ainda usar o gráfico da [resposta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/399268/como-modificar-apenas-a-linha-da-legenda-que-identifica-o-grupo/399283#399283) do usuário [João Pedro Bazzo Vieira](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/109620/jo%c3%a3o-pedro-bazzo-vieira).

Usa-se `guides` para dar outro valor ao `aesthetic` `size` com `override.aes`, e `theme` para tirar a cor do fundo das linhas da legenda.

```
library(ggplot2)

ggplot(economics_long, aes(x = date, y = value01)) +
  geom_line(aes(colour = variable), alpha = 0.5) +
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(size = 2))) +
  theme(legend.key = element_rect(fill = NA))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 3):

Foi dificil achar uma solução. Fiz com algumas cambiarras, mas funcionou. Basicamente, dupliquei o comando `geom_line()` para um intervalo além dos limites do eixo y: `value01+100`.

```
require(ggplot2)
# ANTES
ggplot(economics_long, aes(x=date, y=value01)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=value01,colour=variable),alpha=0.5)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(economics_long$value01)))
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

```
# DEPOIS
ggplot(economics_long, aes(x=date, y=value01)) +
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=value01,colour=variable),alpha=0.5,show.legend = F)+
  geom_line(aes(x=date, y=100+value01,colour=variable),alpha=1,size=2,show.legend = T)+
  scale_y_continuous(limits=c(0,max(economics_long$value01)))

# Warning message:
# Removed 2870 rows containing missing values (geom_path).
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]